# Relations on Z_7?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I have this relation in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ :

$$\mathcal{R}=\{(2,3),(1,0),(3,6)\}$$

Let us take (2,3). My question is: What does this mean? (2 mod 7) and (3 mod 7)?

Comment: It probably needs more context to answer. Can you supply more detail?

Comment: It means the class of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is related to the class of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ under the relation $\mathcal{R}$. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @JoshuaZ i need to check if this relation is a function in $Z_7$. I just don't understand what it means to have a relation in  $Z_7$?

Comment: A relation is just a set of ordered pairs, indicating that they have some relationship. For example, your usual <= on the real numbers is a relation, formed by all the pairs (a,b) where (a<=b). 

A function is a special type of relation where we think of the first element as an input and the second as an output, and we insist that no input has more than one possible output. For example,  {(1,4), (2,3), (5,6)} is a relation that is a function which maps the set {1,2,5} to the set {3,4,6}. But the relation {(1,2),(4,3),(4,8)} is not a function because 4 can be mapped to both 3 and 8.

Comment: In this case, since you are operating mod 7, your elements are just modulus classes, but the behavior of what makes a function or not is identical.